# How to determine what causes ES's query API instability

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Normally, my ES query API takes less than 1s.But sometimes these queries get slow.

cluster consists of three 32G machines (16G allocated to ES).The index consists of 20 primaries and 1 replica, 303,000,000 dos count and 500gb primaries storage size and 1tb storage size.

Here's kibana's monitoring data:

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]`

Personally, I think it's the result of GC. I want to add machines.But I need to find a reason to convince my leader.

Comment: Do you have logs of queries? Is there a certain query that is slow? You can set the thresholds to log the queries with `index.search.slowlog.threshold.*` config settings.

Comment: I configure it.I'm sure it wasn't caused by poor queries.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it could be a GC problem. But can you be more specific? What do you mean by slow?

Anyway it seems the allocated heap is way too large for your needs. You have a collection when the heap is at 12Go ( 75% of 16go ) and it goes back to 5go every time. Its generate huge garbage collection.

You should try to lower the heap to like 10Go and check the impact on performance GC count and GC duration.

I recommands you too read this article https://www.elastic.co/blog/a-heap-of-trouble especially the "Together We Can Prevent Forest Fires" part.

Comment: Thank you, sir.I'll read the article you recommend.I split the original index monthly to reduce the amount of data.Now the amount of data used per query is greatly reduced.The problem seems to have been solved.

Comment: @SuperPirate even with that you should certainly reduce the configured heap size of your nodes :)